# Can I run odoo with a different user than the installation one?

Tags: installation, odoo

I have installed odoo with 'odoo' user name, both for the odoo web app and for the postgreSQL database. Then in the postgreSQL database, I have created another role with minimal priviledges and `ALL` rights on the odoo database.

```
CREATE ROLE toto WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOINHERIT LOGIN NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT 100 ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'my password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE odoo_db TO toto;
```

If I run odoo with user 'toto', here is what I get:

```
ERROR:  relation "base_registry_signaling" already exists
STATEMENT:  CREATE SEQUENCE base_registry_signaling INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1
```

I have not created a system user 'toto' on the web server. Is it the reason for the error? Shall I keep the user with which I have installed odoo?

I have tried another attempt by starting directly the BUILD with another user: 'my'. Here are the project files:

docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    #image: postgres:14
    build: Dockerfiles/postgres/14.0
    user: root
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_db # contains postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_user # contains postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
      - PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/odoo_db_password
    #command: > 
    #  /bin/bash -c "envsubst < '$PASSWORD\_FILE' > ./initdb/initdb.sql"
    restart: always             # run as a service
    volumes:
        - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        #- odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    secrets:
      - postgresql_user # contains my
      - postgresql_password 
      - postgresql_db # contains odoo_db
      - odoo_db_password

  #odoo15:
  web:
    #image: odoo:15
    build: Dockerfiles/odoo/15.0
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "10013:8069"
      - "20013:8072" # live chat
    tty: true
    command: --
#    command: odoo scaffold /mnt/extra-addons/test_module
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER_FILE=/run/secrets/odoo_db_user
      - PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/odoo_db_password
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:fr
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:fr
      # - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh   # if you want to install additional Python packages, uncomment this line!
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
      - ./odoo-data:/var/lib/odoo
    secrets:
      - odoo_db_user
      - odoo_db_password
    restart: always             # run as a service

secrets:
  postgresql_db:
    file: postgresql_bdd
  postgresql_user:
    file: postgresql_utilisateur
  postgresql_password:
    file: postgresql_mdp
  odoo_db_user:
    file: odoo_pg_user
  odoo_db_password:
    file: odoo_pg_pass
```

etc/odoo.conf

```
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /etc/odoo
admin_passwd = my_admin_password
logfile = /etc/odoo/odoo-server.log
db_user = my
db_password = my_db_password
dev_mode = reload
```

initdb.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE my_odoo_db;
CREATE ROLE my WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOINHERIT LOGIN NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT 100 ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'my_db_password';
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE my_odoo_db TO my;
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# install python packages
pip3 install pip --upgrade
pip3 install -r /etc/odoo/requirements.txt

# sed -i 's|raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg)|self.jsonrequest = {}|g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py

DB_ARGS=()
function check_config() {
    param="$1"
    value="$2"
    if grep -q -E "^\s*\b${param}\b\s*=" "$ODOO_RC" ; then       
        value=$(grep -E "^\s*\b${param}\b\s*=" "$ODOO_RC" |cut -d " " -f3|sed 's/["\n\r]//g')
    fi;
    DB_ARGS+=("--${param}")
    DB_ARGS+=("${value}")
}
check_config "db_host" "$HOST"
check_config "db_port" "$PORT"
check_config "db_user" "$USER"
check_config "db_password" "$PASSWORD"
check_config "db_name" "$DBNAME"

case "$1" in
    -- | odoo)
        shift
        if [[ "$1" == "scaffold" ]] ; then
            exec odoo "$@"
        else
            wait-for-psql.py ${DB_ARGS[@]} --timeout=100
            exec odoo -i base "$@" "${DB_ARGS[@]}"
        fi
        ;;
    -*)
        wait-for-psql.py ${DB_ARGS[@]} --timeout=100
        exec odoo -i base "$@" "${DB_ARGS[@]}"
        ;;
    *)
        exec "$@"
esac

exit 1
```

odoo/Dockerfiles/odoo/15.0/Dockerfile (end of it)

```
# Set permissions and Mount /var/lib/odoo to allow restoring filestore and /mnt/extra-addons for users addons
RUN chown my /etc/odoo/odoo.conf \
    && mkdir -p /mnt/extra-addons \
    && chown -R my /mnt/extra-addons
VOLUME ["/var/lib/odoo", "/mnt/extra-addons"]

# Expose Odoo services
EXPOSE 8069 8071 8072

# Set the default config file
ENV ODOO_RC /etc/odoo/odoo.conf

COPY wait-for-psql.py /usr/local/bin/wait-for-psql.py

# Set default user when running the container
USER my
```

odoo/Dockerfiles/odoo/15.0/odoo.conf : the same than above in docker-compose folder

When I run `docker-compose up` and connect to the web container, I get:

```
tail /etc/passwd
odoo:x:101:101::/var/lib/odoo:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

instead of `my`

EDIT : I realise the call to `entrypoint.sh` in the docker-compose file is commented. I have uncommented it and then after database container bootstrap, I get this error when it tries to setup the web container I assume:

```
odoo-db-1   | exécution de l'initialisation après bootstrap... ok
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
```

Comment: Can you please give some more details on how you run Odoo ? It looks like you are trying to recreate a database that already has the tables. Perhaps just drop the database and recreate it ?

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps just need to add in your command that launch Odoo the -w and -r options ?

```
-r DB_USER, --db_user=DB_USER
                        specify the database user name
```

```
-w DB_PASSWORD, --db_password=DB_PASSWORD
                        specify the database password
```

Keep me updated if you need more info, but you can normally launch Odoo with another db user as long as it has the required access rights

Comment: Normaly it is supposed to via the `entrypoint.sh`. I have prevented any default environment variable initialisation by commenting the dedicated lines. Here is another attempt of mine [here on the odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/how-to-launch-the-odoo-application-with-another-system-user-than-odoo-210299). You insights are welcome.